# Error Accessing One-To-Many Relation in Symfony 2 with Doctrine

Tags: php, doctrine, symfony

I've got a simple One-to-Many relation that errors out when I try to iterate through the collection.

from the "One" User.php

```
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="UserMeasurement", mappedBy="measurements")
     */
    protected $measurements;
```

And the corresponding "Many" UserMeasurement.php:

```
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="User", inversedBy="measurements", cascade={"persist"})
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    protected $user;
```

and yet when I try to run from a command:

```
    $query = $em->createQuery(" SELECT user FROM AcmeFooBundle:User user");
    $users = $query->getResult();
    foreach ($users as $user) {
        print count($user->getMeasurements()->toArray());
    }
```

I get the following error:

> [ErrorException]
>   Notice: Undefined index: measurements in
>   /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Symfony/vendor/doctrine/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Persisters/BasicEntityPersister.php
>   line 1280

I've run the `doctrine:schema:update --force` command and it says I'm in sync.

Am I iterating incorrectly?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In your User entity, you have this line:

```
@ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="UserMeasurement", mappedBy="measurements")
```

What you're telling Doctrine is that it should look in the `UserMeasurement` entity for a field named `measurements`, which doesn't exist. What you probably intended was this:

```
@ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="UserMeasurement", mappedBy="user")
```